# ConsenSys. qubernetes tessera connect to different URL

Tags: kubernetes, blockchain, consensys-truffle

I am trying to convert k8s objects available with this git repo to the **Helm chart (with four node quorum network)on GKE**.
https://github.com/ConsenSys/qubernetes

I tried changing the following config map blocks for peers

```
"peer": [ {
    "url": "http://{{ .Release.Name }}-quorum-node1:9001"
   }, {
    "url": "http://{{ .Release.Name }}-quorum-node2:9001"
   }, {
    "url": "http://{{ .Release.Name }}-quorum-node3:9001"
   }, {
    "url": "http://{{ .Release.Name }}-quorum-node4:9001"
   }],
```

If I create a helm chart with the name **consensys-nw** it should ideally be able to resolve these URLs

But when I check logs for **tessera** I got errors like

```
c.q.t.partyinfo.PartyInfoPoller - Error javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: consensys-quorum-node1 when connecting to http://consensys-quorum-node1:9001/
```

Ideally, it should connect **http://consensys-nw-quorum-node1:9001/** and not **http://consensys-quorum-node1:9001/**

Comment: do the services for "concensys-quorum-node1" (and node2, etc.) exist? if so, do they have endpoints associtated with the service?

Comment: basically i am trying to create helm chart and initally i created helm chart with name consensys. but later on i uninstall and install with consensys-nw. for safer side i deleted even pv,pvc as consensys using lot of info from storage (by kubectl) but it is still pointing some old urls

Comment: then i think you are missing the services or they don't have endpoints associated with them. 

can you add the output of "kubectl get service --namespace $namespace" and "kubectl get endpoints --namespace $namespace" to your question?